# Reading Object returns undefined Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

```
 Arr1 [
    {id: 300,
    uploads: [
        {idOne: value},
        {idTwo: value}
       ]
    },
    {blah: value, 
     uploads: [
        {idOne: value},
        {idTwo: value}
       ]
    }
]
```

This Object is being read like this

```
 this.activatedRoute.parent.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.someService.getSubmissions(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(submissions => console.log('subs', submissions.map(x=>x)))
```

results in

The Object as shown above.

And

```
 this.activatedRoute.parent.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.someService.getSubmissions(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(submissions => console.log('subs', submissions.map(x=>x.id)))
```

Displays id:300

But when I go

```
 this.activatedRoute.parent.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.someService.getSubmissions(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(submissions => console.log('subs', submissions.map(x=>x.uploads)))
```

It logs undefined. And I can not reasonably detect why.

This is within the onInit() of an Angular component.

Comment: What's the purpose of `.map(x=>x)` ?

Comment: Also, `myObjectName` is an array. It seems to contains some objects. Do those objects all have `uploads` property ?

Comment: to be able to .map(x=>x.id), as submissions.id is not working.

Comment: Yes they do all have the uploads property.

Comment: You should read [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) documentation. `.map(x => x)` will copy your array, which is useless in your case since you call `map` a second time. Also, given the pseudo-code you provided, no, `uploads` is _NOT_ inside all your objects.

Comment: @FabiooFabiulous do not write `(params: Params) => ...`. it is dangerous. Also the identity mapping is nonsense as Serge K already noted.

Comment: @AluanHaddad care to explain why is that dangerous?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo imagine that `params` is typed as `Observable<any>`. If so, any annotation on `params` will pass the type checker since `any` is assignable to and from any other type. This will mislead the reader since it reads as if the `Observable<T>` has a meaningful element type (just redundantly overspecified) but in reality it is acting like a type assertion. An explicit type assertion is much better practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, updated the above with forEach:-

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.params.switchMap(params => {
 this.someService.getSubmissions(+params['id']))
 .subscribe(submissions => {
   submissions.forEach(x=>{
      if(x.id){
        console.log("id",x.id);
      }
      if(x.uploads){
      console.log("uploads",x.uploads);
      }

    })
 });
});
```

Comment: The ID's are logged. The Uploads not.

Comment: @FabiooFabiulous If `uploads` aren't logged in this case, then `submissions` is not defined as you stated.